# Как пользоваться скелетной анимацией из DragonBones (или хотя бы Spine) в libgdx?

Tags: java, анимация, libgdx, графика

Имеется DragonBones, в нём делаются анимации. Также есть runtime, который вроде как официально одобрен и [добавлен в репозиторий](https://github.com/DragonBones/DragonBonesJAVA) наравне с остальными рантаймами под другие движки.

В этом репозитории упоминается, что он запускается как-то с помощью Egret. Но как я понял, это другая IDE со своим языком (может быть, я ошибаюсь). В любом случае я пишу в Intelij Idea и работаю с движком там. Абсолютно не понимаю, как им пользоваться, не нашел документации по методам и просто не знаю, как подступиться к изучению и с чего начать.

Есть второй вариант, которым многие пользуются, но даже его я не смог осилить. В DragonBones есть возможность конвертировать созданную анимацию в формат известной программы Spine, которая также имеет [официальный runtime конкретно для Libgdx](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/spine-runtimes/tree/3.6/spine-libgdx). Но не понимаю как работать даже с этим. Установил, попытался запустить, мне написало, что я не установил нужную jdk, хотя до этого я кодил и все нормально устанавливал.

Помогите разобраться, с чего начать? Как портировать в движок хотя бы простую скелетную анимацию с одной костью и простым наклонением? В идеале хочу понять, как отображать в движке изменения Mesh-ей, и в принципе мне этого будет достаточно.

Другие движки не предлагать, у меня стоит цель выучить Java, поэтому был выбран движок libgdx для этого. И не предлагать покупать Spine. один хрен, не понимаю, как работать с рантаймом, да и денег таких нет.